# How to remove a specific folder from a previous installation

Tags: inno-setup

I install my program using Inno Setup, I created an update iss and I'm trying to remove a folder from the previous installation like this:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#MyAppIcoName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\runtime\bin\client"; 

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

But it is not removing and no error appears during compilation or execution. It just doesn't remove it.
What am I doing wrong?

```
;[UninstallRun]
;Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Parameters: "/DIR=""{app}\runtime\bin\client"" /NOCLOSEAPPLICATIONS"; Flags: waituntilterminated

;[UninstallDelete]
;Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{app}\runtime\bin\client"

;[UninstallDelete]
;Type: files; Name: "{app}\runtime\bin\client\*"

;[UninstallRun]
;Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C rmdir /S /Q ""{app}\runtime\bin\client"""; Flags: waituntilterminated; RunOnceId: DelTreeClientFolder

;[UninstallRun]
.Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Parameters: "/DIR=""{app}"""; Flags: waituntilterminated; RunOnceId: DelTreeClientFolder

;[UninstallRun]
;Filename: "{uninstallexe}"; Parameters: "/DelTree ""{app}\runtime\bin\client"""; Flags: waituntilterminated; RunOnceId: DelTreeClientFolder
```

Comment: Please post log file  and format the code in your question properly.